# Get the currently selected radio button in a jquery ui buttonset without binding to click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have radio buttons like this:

```
<div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioOption" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioOption" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radioOption" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
</div>
```

And apply the button set like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#radio").buttonset();
});
```

I need to get the selected radio button without binding to the click event.

Comment: You might find this link useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329579/jquery-check-current-state-of-radio-button-and-hide-div

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Damn just realised my selecter had a typo, but if it helps anyone else:

If you dont want to use the click event, which I didn't  you could do the following:
If you're looking for the element it self use:

```
$("#radio :radio:checked");
```

If you're looking for the id of the element use:

```
$("#radio :radio:checked").attr('id');
```

If you're need to know what the text of the value selected then this should work:

```
$("#radio :radio:checked + label").text();
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer that actually does what you want, i.e. *gets* the radio value at any point in time, rather than requiring you to store the value elsewhere every time the user changes it.  WAY more elegant and maintainable. +1

Comment: I'm using an On/Off buttonset, so I set my radio values as `value='on'` and `value='off'`.  This makes it easy and readable: `$('#radio :radio:checked').val() == 'on'`

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
$("input:radio[name=radioOption]").click(function(){
      var value = $(this).attr("id");
      alert(value);
})
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zM5L9/)

Answer (score 3):

As I see, there is not such event for buttonset on jquery ui. You can see [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#event-create).

You need to write manual jquery bind like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
        $("#radio input").bind("click",function(){
               // do whatever you want to do with clicked button
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

When I click in a button I call one function, it takes parameters from the buttonSet:

```
$("#button").click( function()
{

var params = $("input[name=radio]:checked").val();
alert(params);

});
```

In your case if you do this, I think it should work:

```
var params = $("input[name=radioOption]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the `value` attribute to every `input` as follows:

```
<div id="radio">         
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioOption" checked="checked" value="first"/><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioOption" value="second"/><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radioOption" value="third"/><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
</div>
```