# How can I show a part of form after a yes/no radio?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Well my question is as the title says , specifically I have a form that I store on a database and not all the fields are required , more specifically we are selling products and there is a promo price that can be added but I don't want to show the input place for the promo price until I get a answer (if yes then show it else no need to show that part of the form) how can I process that ? 
I am working on laravel (I use basic php at the moment because I am still learning) if that helps.
Edit : After some search I found a script that I tried adapting to my code , here is the new version :

```
<h1>Add a new product</h1>
<form id="someform" method="post" action="/managers">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{--        the csrf is used for security purposes ps: we can't proceed without it , it gives error 419--}}
    <div>
        <select name="market">
            @foreach($marketname as $mname)
            <option name="market" value="{{$mname->managerId}}">{{$mname->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Product name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price (mad)">
    </div>
    <h5>Is there a promo on the product</h5>
    <input type="radio" name="quest" id="rad">
    <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="quest" value="No">
    <label for="No">No</label>
    <div class="test">
        <input type="text" name="promo" placeholder="Promo price">
        <label style="display:block">The promo end date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="promod">
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
        $(function () {
            $('.test').hide();

            $("input[name=quest]:radio").click(function () {
                if ($('input[name=quest]:checked').val() == "Yes") {
                    $('.test').show();
                } else if ($('input[name=quest]:checked').val() == "No") {
                    $('.test').hide();

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Add product</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is nothing happens , I read that we can't use js on blade files , how can I use it then (I don't know js I just copied and edited).

Comment: can you show your stuff plz.?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra there it is.

Comment: on page  load  you can manage by PHP but after that you need js to show or hide

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I figured out so , but how to process it using php? I thought of using different form for the radio because the content of the product's form are stored to the database but then I can't use a form inside of another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - Check current state of radio button and hide div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329579/jquery-check-current-state-of-radio-button-and-hide-div)

Comment: @NitinKhanna yeah I think it's the same thing that I want to do on click show the promo section , but I don't know any javascript so I couldn't adapt that to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .change for what you want

```
$("input[@name='lom']").change(function(){
    // Do something interesting here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript 
onclick of the radio button then produce another element you want to show

Comment: Thank you , I tried doing so (I looked it up) but it still didn't work , can you check why ? ps: I am working with laravel blade file